# Sample mean of categories

Tags: probability, statistics, means

I have a sample of 73 students who have picked these bottles as their preferred choice.
[Table of sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUiI7.png)

Is there a way of taking the sample mean based on this data alone?
I understand how to use the equation $\bar{X}$ in most cases but i can't see how i can use it on this type of data.

Comment: Why do you want the average? The mode is suitable for categorical data in general and particularly fine in your case.

Comment: Its a part of my school project, the project asks for us to calculate the sample mean, sample median, sample variance, sample standard deviation. So would the Mode be equivalent to taking the sample mean?

Comment: No, they are not equivalent (or even analogous) in this way. There's likely an oversight on your instructors' part and my advice is go talk to them.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: The sample mean *of what quantity*?